# Python script called by udev rule unable to import modules ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, udev

I have a udev rule which triggers a python script whenever a block device (USB drive) is attached/detached from the system. The udev rule seems to be firing correctly, but the python script it calls cant start because it's missing an import. The import error I get it ModuleNotFound error. The udev script calls a bash script which calls:
`python3 /root/projects/script.py --arg "$1" --arg2 >> /tmp/python3.log 2>&1 &`

In python3.log, I see the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

I have installed this module as root via `pip3 install requests`, and indeed the script works fine when manually called from the root shell, but somehow being called by udev doesn't work.

If I run from root terminal `pip3 install requests` I get `Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (2.27.1)`

I assume this is a pathing issue? How do I go about figuring out why python can't find this module?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way python determines it's "path". I don't know the best practice solution for this, but here's what I did. From a python console that does work (`sudo python3`) I do `import requests` then `print(requests)` to get the full path. This gives me `<module 'requests' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py'>`

So in my script.py I add this to the top

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages"))
```

And the issue is solved